# selecting list of columns from dataframe to convert to subset

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function , for that at the input i am giving a list of modifying columns .
for eg: sample data is

```
    dataa<-data.frame(
      aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
    col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
    col2=c(2,1,1,7,4,1,2,7,5,7,2,6,2,2,6,3,4,3,2,5,7,5,6,4,4,6,5,6,4,1,7,3,2,7,7,2,3,7,2,4)
    )
```

my requirement is like , i can create any more than one cuts like below, or can be a list of cuts
may be i am trying to recode my dataset

```
dataa$col3 <- ifelse(dataa$aa == "y",1,0)
dataa$col4 <- ifelse(dataa$col2 == 7,1,0)
```

so now in my function requirement i want a subset of selected variables for calculation.
for eg:

```
#i am applying my function like this
dat1 = dataa
var1 = "col1" # variable for which calculation will be done
grouping_var = list(dataa$col3,dataa$col4)
total_var= TRUE

#fun_1 <- function(dat1,var1,grouping_var,total_var){
  total_col <- ifelse(total_var== TRUE,1,0)
  var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
  var2 <- dat1[unlist(grouping_var)] # i am trying to create a subset dataframe of selected grouping_var
  #var2 <- data.frame(sapply(grouping_var,c)) # i have tried this too
  
  dat1 <- dat1 %>% select(!!var1,!!var2) 
# so after this line i would have a subset to calculations accordingly
var_lab(dat1[[1]]) <- ""
  var_lab(dat1[[2]]) <- ""
  tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(total(),dat1[[1]],dat1[[2]])
  tab1 <- as.data.frame(tab1)
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to select columns based on the values of the column.

An easy way would be to pass them as character vector and select. Try :

```
dat1 = dataa
var1 = "col1" 
grouping_var = c('col3', 'col4') #Passing columns as character vector
total_var= TRUE

#fun_1 <- function(dat1,var1,grouping_var,total_var){
total_col <- as.integer(total_var)
#total_col <- ifelse(total_var== TRUE,1,0)
dat1 <- dat1[grouping_var]
expss::var_lab(dat1[[1]]) <- ""
expss::var_lab(dat1[[2]]) <- ""
tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(expss::total(),dat1[[1]],dat1[[2]])
tab1 <- as.data.frame(tab1)

#}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak,  i am getting error below
>   dat1 <- dat1 %>% select(!!var1,!!var2)
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<
  col3: double
  col4: double
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.

Comment: I don't have that line in my code. I have removed it. You don't need `select` since we are doing `var2 <- dat1[grouping_var]`.

Comment: actually it required that line , because in that line i am trying to create a subset so that that i can apply
tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(total(),dat1[[1]],dat1[[2]])
dat1[[1]] # 1st column in subset dataset
dat1[[2]] # all grouping variables

Comment: Use `dat1 <- dat1[grouping_var]` to subset the dataframe `dat1`. You don't need `var1`, var2`. Check updated answer.

Comment: still doesn't work...may i am not able to make you understand everything

Comment: dat1 <- dat1 %>% select(!!var1,!!var2) 
# so after this line i would have a subset to calculations accordingly
for one columns it was working perfectly fine...
so previously i had only one column for var2 but now i have a list of more than one columns  , so var2 will be a list of n columns.
or may be we have any other solution lets say

tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(expss::total(),dat1[[1]],c(grouping variables))

Comment: @sanuali0123 Why are you sticking with `select` ? I am trying to do this without `select` as shown in my answer. Maybe you want to change this line `tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(expss::total(),dat1[[1]],dat1[[2]])` to `tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(expss::total(),dat1)` so that you don't have to select individual columns. Or maybe I am confused and don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: because without the summary will be messy, not as per required